# Issues after importing Functions from a local file in Python 3.7.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to import a set of functions from an external file into my main file. The primary reason is for the sake of keeping things tidy.

I have a command input screen where the user types in a command and then a command is executed based on what they entered. I want to store the commands in functions, and these functions be stored in a separate file. Example Pseudo code:

```
import other_file_example as other

clear = lambda: system.os('clear') or None

def foo_func():
   Do stuff
   other.do_stuff_in_main()
```

External File  :

```
import main_file

def do_stuff_in_main():
   clear()
   execute_some_func_from main()
```

The issue i am having is that i can't, by default, access the functions, objects, and modules defined in main without doing a ' From main import * ' or some other form of import. This, however, drives my linter crazy. i'm importing everything into my Commands.py file then importing that into my Main.py file. So i'm double importing it. It works as intended. But my linter gives me a stack of issues complaining that Function *****() already exists or some similar error. My question is, should i ignore the linter? Or is there a better way to do this without there being any errors thrown while maintaining the intended functionality of the program.

A follow up question would be :
What are the consequences of doing imports like this? Are there any performance, memory, or any other issues that stem from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. I will leave this up for anyone who has a similar issue.
I solved this by adding a source module argument to my function. Whenever i call the function from the other file i pass in a reference to the current namespace. This allows the function to execute and access the objects and functions from the main file without doing any circular imports.

```
# file that contains my functions commands.py

def game_exit(source_module):
     confirm = input(source_module.term.red('Are you sure you want to exit?\nType y/n : '))
     if str(confirm) == 'y':
          source_module.cls()
          exit
     else:
          source_module.command_prompt()
```

MainCLI file:

```
# this is the mainCLI module

import commands
import sys
import os
from blessings import Terminal

term = Terminal()    
cls = lambda: os.system('clear') or None
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]

commands.game_exit(current_module)

def command_prompt():
    input('Type a command and press enter...')
    if input:
        do stuff......
```

Finally the main.py file:

```
import mainCLI

if __name__ == "__main__":
      mainCLI.cls()
      mainCLI.main_loop()
```

This works perfectly so far. The code above is greatly condensed from the actual code used. But hopefully this explains how i solved the issue. Good luck peoples.